# (Java) ArrayList length becomes zero after a nonzero method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using an ArrayList to store objects that are "valid" for the purposes of my program and referencing it later in the same class file.

```
    private static ArrayList<TownResource> validResources = new ArrayList<>();
```

A public method is called, which then calls a private method within the class that makes `validResources`'s size nonzero.

```
 public static boolean detection(int row, int col, TownResource[][] rArray, ResourceEnum[][][] bT, BuildingEnum buildingType) {
            int checkTime = 0;
            int patternIndex = 0;
            try {
                for (int i = 1; i < checkTime+1; i++) {
                    if (compare(row, col, rArray, buildingTemplate[patternIndex], buildingType)) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < validResources.size(); j++) {
                            validResources.get(j).setScannedBuilding(buildingType);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Size at compare" + validResources.size());
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                //System.out.println("Out of bounds exception?");
            }
        return false;
    }
```

The compare method is a private method that on one condition, may clear `validResources`.

```
private static boolean compare(int row, int col, TownResource[][] rArray, ResourceEnum[][] buildingTemplate, BuildingEnum buildingType) {
    for (int r = 0; r < buildingTemplate.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < buildingTemplate[r].length; c++) {
            if (match(rArray[row+r][col+c], buildingTemplate[r][c])) {
                //System.out.println("Successful comparison at " + (row+r) + ", " + (col+c));
            }
            else {
                validResources.clear();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`match` is what sets `validResources` to be nonzero in size:

```
private static boolean match(TownResource toBeChecked, ResourceEnum checker) {
    if (checker == ResourceEnum.NONE) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (toBeChecked.getResource() == checker) {
        validResources.add(toBeChecked);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, when I know `validResources` to be nonzero in size(this causes detection to return true which triggers a new method `placement`), it becomes zero.

```
public static void placement(TownResource[][] rArray, Building[][] bArray, BuildingEnum building) {
    // other parts of method commented out for example
    System.out.println(validResources.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < validResources.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Is this statement firing?");
        System.out.println(validResources.get(i).getResource());
        validResources.get(i).setResource(ResourceEnum.NONE);
}
```

Have I declared `validResources` incorrectly? Or is there something else at play?
Thank you.

Comment: It feels like you want to run through the [mcve] exercise here, first, because this much code suggests you haven't yet homed in on which function and while line is responsible for the clearing, which reducing forces you to find.

Comment: Static fields and methods with this much code seem like part of the problem to me.

Comment: You have an empty catch block. You need to log or rethrow the exception

Answer (score 0):

This was an error in how I executed `detection()`. This method is called by another method within another class when iterating through a 2D array. The ArrayList `validResources` becomes nonempty in one check, but gets overwritten by another as a result of the program not calling `placement` until every object in the 2D array had `detection` called on it. I changed this to call `placement` immediately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).